# Passing Pointer to Function Only Changes Value in Function Scope

Tags: c++, function, pointers

It seems I am doing something wrong in passing these pointers as arguements to my getImages function. Testing my code showed that in the function getImages, my pointers home and start were able to take on appropriate values. But testing them again back in main scope their values were both 0. I have included the relevant code snippets below. Please tell me how I can correctly pass these arguments. Thank you.

```
void getImages(IplImage *home, IplImage *start);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    IplImage *home = 0;
    IplImage *start = 0;

    getImages(home,start);
```

Comment: Pass them in by reference

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how pointers work; if you do `home = something;` inside `getImages` it won't change `home` in `main`, same as it wouldn't if the parameters weren't pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass the pointers by reference:

```
void getImages(IplImage *&home, IplImage *&start);
```

Comment: I hadn't thought to use both symbols together like that. Thank you.

Comment: @LucaDelSignore If the problem is solved, you should mark the appropriate answer as accepted.

Comment: Actually, the problem persists. Inside the function the pointers have their correct hexadecimal values, while outside they remain 0. I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: It seems like you are right. I found other people saying similar things about passing references to pointers. I think maybe something else may be causing the problem but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are variables that hold addresses. If you pass in pointers to `getImages` then you should dereference those pointers to access the actual object. However since you've set your `home` and `start` pointers to 0, no memory was allocated to the `IplImage` object and therefore it doesnt exist. As a result, derefencing non-allocated memory will cause your compiler to complain.

You should pass in by reference:

```
void getImages(IplImage &home, IplImage &start)
{
    // do something with home
    // do something with start
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    IplImage home;
    IplImage start;

    getImages(home,start);
}
```

Note above that `IplImage` is allocated memory on the stack since references can't be null, unlike pointers, references need memory allocated prior to use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But I don't think that is legal syntax. The * symbol must be used to indicate that a parameter is a pointer to an IplImage object and not the object itself. Still, I tested this, and it resulted in the expected compilation error.